# Emberjs Rendering other Templates within another template

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, rendering, router

I would like to render the template 'location' within a sidebar in the template 'permit'. 
My code is a replica of the code shown on emberjs.com's rendering templates example but the 'location' template is either not loading at all, or loading just the 'locations' template in repeat but not rendering the original html in the 'permit' template. So the location.hbs is displayed but not inside the sidebar it's been assigned to.

Here's some code :D

```
<!-- Right Sidebar (a small piece of the 'permit' template) START -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-super-float-right-col">
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-float-right-col">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="float-right-col">
          {{outlet location}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Right Sidebar END -->


VpcYeoman.PermitRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('location');
    }
});
```

router.js

```
VpcYeoman.Router.map(function () {
...
  this.resource('permit', { path: '/permit/:permit_id' });
...
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/ is once again being vague and of little help.

emberjs community assemble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a named outlet, but aren't telling it to render into that named outlet.  The code you are using is saying render the `location` template, instead of the default template (`permit`).  You would do something along the lines below

```
this.render('location', {   // the template to render
  into: 'permit',                // the route to render into
  outlet: 'location',              // the name of the outlet in the route's template
  //controller: 'blogPost'        // the controller to use for the template
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, kingpin!

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/ is quite misleading when compared to the solution.

What is written in the PermitRoute must be the same as what is written in the .hbs file, with the addition of a colon.

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ render:'location'});
}
```

so what would be put into the HTML would not be {{outlet location}}, as their website claims, which will render only 'location' and not 'permit' but {{render 'location'}} will render a template within a template.

Comment: or, you could still use your named outlet and do `this.render();` (that will render permit, by convention) and `this.render('location', {outlet: 'location'});` to render the sidebar. The key point is that if you override `renderTemplate` you need to call super or call `this.render();` if you still want the default render to happen.